# Ruby &! (and bang) Operator

Tags: ruby, syntax

I was playing around with Ruby, and I came across `&!`, so I played around with it a bit:

```
true &! true #=> false
true &! false #=> true
true &! nil #=> true
true &! {:test=>:foo} #=> false
false &! true #=> false
false &! false #=> false
false &! nil #=> false
false &! {:test=>:foo} #=> false
nil &! true #=> false
nil &! false #=> false
nil &! nil #=> false
nil &! {:test=>:foo} #=> false
```

Looks like `value && !value` so far, but...

```
{:test=>:foo} &! true
```

gave an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `&' for {:test=>:foo}:Hash
        from (irb):23:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
        from (irb):23:in `each'
        from (irb):23:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):23:in `each'
        from (irb):23
        from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

So, I assume it's 2 different operators? If so, what do they do? I don't think I've seen them. Is it safe to use for comparing values?

PS: Here's the script I used to test this:

```
test.each {|v| test.each{ |v2| print "#{v.inspect} &! #{v2.inspect} #=> " ; p v &! v2 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a &! b` is the same as `a & (!b)`

We can see this with ruby [parser](https://github.com/whitequark/parser):

```
Parser::CurrentRuby.parse("true &! false") 
#=> 
#s(:send,
# s(:true), :&,
# s(:send,
#   s(:false), :!))
```

`&` is the bitwise-and operator, however on boolean values and nil it acts the same as `&&`. In ruby all hashes are truthy, so `!{foo: 'bar'}` is always `false`.

Comment: @penne12 Is this all you wanted to know?

Comment: @sawa I just really appreciated the fact that the answer included the sexp - helped me understand it better - your answer was also very helpful,

Answer (score 1):

Method `&` is defined on `true`, `false`, `nil`, but not on a hash.

`true & obj` returns `false` if `obj` is `nil` or `false`, `true` otherwise.
`false & obj` and `nil & obj` return `false`. `obj` is always evaluated as it is the argument to a method call—there is no short-circuit evaluation in this case.

In short, read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

It's two different operators. `&` is bitwise and, and `!` is negation, of course. So `true` and `false` and `nil` know about bitwise and, but not hashes.